# Why is <body> element in the tab sequence in ember application. clean to make address bar not in the tab sequence

Tags: javascript, ember.js, tabs, tabindex, address-bar

I have a really simple form in Ember.js which has 3 form elements. But the tab will go through 5 element and an element I can't see, I used document.activeElement in console, then I got a  element, it doesn't have a tabindex attribute. Is there anyone know why the element in the tab sequence? 
And also, what's the most clean way to skip the address bar(url field) in the tab sequence. Thanks.

Comment: You can remove an element from the tab index be setting tab index to -1.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work

Comment: Don't "skip the address bar", even if you can-  by doing that you are violating what the user expects when using a browser.